# How do I declare extra properties in project level `build.gradle.kts` file?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I write this Groovy code to declare top level versions of the dependencies in the project level `build.gradle.kts` file written in Kotlin DSL code. How do I write it correctly?

```
buildscript {
   ext {
       compose_version = '1.5.3'
       lifecycle_version = '2.5.1'
       room_version = '2.5.2'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can declare top-level configuration and variables in the `build.gradle.kts` file on top of the project using Kotlin DSL for Gradle.

Here I use `buildscript { extra.apply { set() } }`.
This way we can declare common dependency versions to all the modules in an app.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    extra.apply {
        set("compose_version", "1.5.3")
        set("lifecycle_version", "2.5.1")
        set("room_version", "2.5.2")
    }
}
```

Then, we can use the global variable in the module level `build.gradle.kts` indicating the version as `${rootProject.extra["library_version"]}`

```
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:${rootProject.extra["room_version"]}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        lifecycleVersion = "2.5.1"
    }
}
```